# Stuck in an infinite loop when trying to use publish in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
%Question 1 


y=dtmfsig(150006260); 

%a
t= linspace(0,0.9,7200) 
plot(t,y)
title('DTMF time signal')
xlabel('t (sec)') 
ylabel(' y(t)' ) 




% Part B

fLH= [697, 770, 852, 941, 1209, 1336, 1477] 


%Signal divided into 3 sections 
fs= 8000 
T=1/fs


y1= y(1:2400);     
y2=y(2401:4800); 
y3=y(4801:7200);


% Seven point DTFT 

Dy1= freqz(y1, 1, 2*pi*T*fLH);
Dy1n= abs(Dy1)

%   1



Dy2= freqz(y2, 1, 2*pi*T*fLH);
Dy2n= abs(Dy2)

%   3 

Dy3= freqz(y3, 1, 2*pi*T*fLH);
Dy3n= abs(Dy3)


% 2


% In each of these sections I used the given keypad to determine what my
% output would be based on the maximums in the matrix. I wrote what those
% numbers would be under each set of commands but to recap they are in
% order 1,3,2

%c  

t1= 600:1:1600 
 %First DTFT (Need to put points in Dy1n in) 
Dc1= freqz(y1, 1, t1.*2.*pi.*T)
Dc1n= abs(Dc1)
plot(t1, Dc1n./abs(max(Dc1n)))
title(' normalized spectrum of decode key 5') 
xlabel(' frequency (Hz) ')
ylabel(' magnitude') 


Dc2= freqz(y2, 1, t1.*2.*pi.*T)
Dc2n=abs(Dc2)
plot(t1, Dc1n./abs(max(Dc2n)))
title('normalized spectrum of decode key 3')
xlabel('frequency (Hz)') 
ylabel('magnitude')



Dc3= freqz(y3, 1,t1.*2.*pi.*T)
Dc3n=abs(Dc3) 
plot(t1, Dc1n./abs(max(Dc3n)))
title('normalized spectrum of decode key 8')
xlabel('frequency (Hz)') 
ylabel('magnitude')


% In this secion I computed the DTFT of the three segements that I divided
% the signal into and then graphed them. 


%d 

% For the last part of this question I created a table that shows the
% normalized values for the 3 different key values that are displayed in
% the graphs above
d= [fLH; Dy1; Dy2; Dy3]; 

fprintf('%6s  |  %10s %10s %10s\n', 'f', 'key 5', 'key 3', 'key 8') ; 
fprintf('-----|------------------------------------------\n'); 
fprintf('%6.d| %10.3f %10.3f %10.3f\n',d); 

publish('lab2question1.m','pdf')
```

When ever I publish this I wind up in a loop of figures popping up that doesnt stop unless I click ctrl+c.....Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I am trying to create a pdf that has all the graphs and comments I put into this code. First time using publish and when I look at the help function in matlab for the publish command it seems as though  am doing it correctly.

Comment: Two asides: first, you should terminate those commands with semicolons; otherwise there is an awful lot of useless output in the command window. Second, when asking a question on SO, you should [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just pasting the whole script as is.  Many people will read a code sample with several lines; few will want to scroll and scroll in search of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The command `publish` *executes* the script whose name is given, and records the output.  Your mistake is inserting this command into the script itself. This results in an infinite loop: the script runs, then at the end encounters `publish` command, which means it has to run again, so it does, and then encounters `publish`, etc.

You should invoke

```
publish('lab2question1.m','pdf')
```

from the **command window**, not from the script itself.