# Matlab: Publish function runs endless loop

Tags: matlab, infinite-loop, matlab-uitable

I've created an .m file that pulls and sorts data into a UI table, then I have the ability to publish this to either html or pdf form. I can click in the GUI of matlab publish button and it perfectly prints the table once to publication, but if i insert:
publish('MTRChecks.m','html');
at the end of the code, then the program will loop endlessly regenerating the same table without publishing it.

I am using Matlab 2013 B, while not ideal it is my only option.

Comment: Welcome! This is probably not enough code to tell what is going on. Can you make a small sample that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900851/stuck-in-an-infinite-loop-when-trying-to-use-publish-in-matlab), you are most probably using the `publish` call in the wrong way, as `publish` function call takes care of running the script provided as the first argument, adding the call at the bottom of the script would lead such an infinite call.

Comment: If you find that a question is a duplicate of another question, flag it as duplicate. That is much more helpful than linking the duplicate question into an answer. Thanks!